# how to retrieve data in struts using PreparedStatements with the help of ArrayList?

Tags: java, struts, prepared-statement

I am a beginner in struts want to be practice in DAO. I want to know how to retrieve data from table using `PreparedStatement` and `ArrayList`?

Comment: PreparedStatements has nothing to do with STRUTS, nor ArrayList...

Comment: @OMG i would like to know how to retrieve using both only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good lightweight and easy to use database access library is [Jakarta Commons DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/).

It is just a thin wrapper on top of JDBC that takes care of finally cleaning up resources. No OR-mapping and things like that.

With it you can write code like

```
 List<Object[]> result = new QueryRunner(dataSource)
    .query("select * from the_table where x > ?",
      new ArrayListHandler(), 1234);
```

Comment: @OMG: No, I am not. I just don't want to expose anyone to raw JDBC. That API is too brutal.